# Need exact location of users on my website (PHP, Jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, google-api, geolocation

I used Google geo locations and other resources to get users location also via IP's , Lang and Lat.

But all the results are wrong. Need to integrate location detector like on mobile phones which are always accurate.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried `navigator.geolocation`

Comment: In a website running computer, the location may not be accurate. Because, it don't have a gps device attached to it

Comment: yes I used navigator.geolocation but locations are not accurate.

Comment: Yes on computers GPS device not attached but is there any option i can get accurate location on computer like google does when you type where I am on google search. ?

Comment: can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the package [GeoIP2](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php) (superseded [GeoIP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php)). You can install the package with composer and link either a [free database](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) or purchase a more accurate database from [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-precision-country-service) dependent on the level of accuracy you would like (city, country etc..).

Example code taken from [Github](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php):

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

// This creates the Reader object, which should be reused across
// lookups.
$reader = new Reader('/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP2-City.mmdb');

// Replace "city" with the appropriate method for your database, e.g.,
// "country".
$record = $reader->city('128.101.101.101');

print($record->country->isoCode . "\n"); // 'US'
print($record->country->name . "\n"); // 'United States'
print($record->country->names['zh-CN'] . "\n"); // '美国'

print($record->mostSpecificSubdivision->name . "\n"); // 'Minnesota'
print($record->mostSpecificSubdivision->isoCode . "\n"); // 'MN'

print($record->city->name . "\n"); // 'Minneapolis'

print($record->postal->code . "\n"); // '55455'

print($record->location->latitude . "\n"); // 44.9733
print($record->location->longitude . "\n"); // -93.2323
```

The free database is not bad but I would recommend purchasing a professional database if you need it to be as accurate as possible without the use of GPS. This is mainly because the list is updated frequently when IP blocks have been sold etc...

Comment: Thank you so much @Kitson88

Comment: @Paritosh No worries. Don't forget to mark the question as answered. I would also advise on marking your other questions as well. To see how the system works, look at the following http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work